# Setting up docker containers with nat

Tags: containers, iptables, docker, nat

I am setting up two docker containers

```
     container1                 container2
     |        |                     |
    eth0     eth1                   |
     |        |                    eth1
   docker0   docker1<----------------
     |            
     |
   internet
```

docker0 and docker1 are the bridges.

I have ip forwarding to 1 in both host and in containers. 
I have setup

```
iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE in container 1
```

Still i am not able to ping anything from container 2 to internet. I can see that packets are being received at eth1 of container 1.

```
OS: ubuntu 13.10
docker version: 0.11.1, build fb99f99
```

Am i missing some configuration?

Steps to reproduce:

```
SERV=$(docker run --privileged=true -i -d -t -v ~/Projects/code/myproject/build:/build:ro debian:7.4 /bin/bash)
CLI=$(docker run --privileged=true -i -d -t -v ~/Projects/code/myproject/build:/build:ro debian:7.4 /bin/bash)
sudo pipework br1 $SERV 10.1.0.1/8
sudo pipework br1 $CLI 10.1.0.3/8
```

In $SERV:
   iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

In $CLI
   Disable the interface eth0. Set default route to eth1 interface.

Now ping is happening to 10.1.0.1 from $CLI but not to the internet.

Comment: how did you setup eth0 and eth1 within container1? using pipework, host networking or other?

Comment: I used pipework for that.

Comment: Could you provide a step-by-step way to reproduce?

Comment: Added the steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, it should work as you described. Maybe the default route is not configured correctly.
This is what I did:

```
SERV=$(docker run -i --privileged -d -t debian:7.4 /bin/bash)
CLI=$(docker run --privileged -i -d -t debian:7.4 /bin/bash)

docker exec -ti $CLI ping google.de  # Internet up

docker exec -ti $CLI ip link set eth0 down
docker exec -ti $CLI ping google.de  # Internet down

pipework br1 $SERV 10.1.0.1/8
pipework br1 $CLI 10.1.0.2/8

docker exec -ti $SERV apt-get install -y iptables
docker exec -ti $SERV iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
docker exec -ti $CLI ip route add default via 10.1.0.1 dev eth1
docker exec -ti $CLI ping google.de  # Internet up

docker exec -ti $CLI apt-get install -y traceroute
docker exec -ti $CLI traceroute google.de
```

Comment: Hi, I used the commands that you put here, and everything from my container works fine and my container can ping my host, however host cannot ping the container any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way iptables is changed is when executed from Docker host on a containers run with

**--privileged**

Here is a script:

iptables along with a couple of tools are installed during the image build (Dcokerfile)
*inetutils-traceroute iputils-tracepath iptables*

Here I use "[phusion-dockerbase](http://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/)", you can use whatever image you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

### ==> Install & configure iptable during build
#RUN sudo apt-get install -y inetutils-traceroute iputils-tracepath iptables
# Build the image 
#sudo docker build -t mybimage -f phusion-dockerbase .

### container1
C1=$(docker run --privileged -i -d -t mybimage /bin/bash)
sudo docker exec -ti $C1 iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sleep 2
sudo pipework br6 -i eth1 $C1 192.168.66.1/24

### container2
lxterminal -e "sudo docker run -ti --name c2name mybimage /bin/bash"
sleep 2
C2="$(sudo docker ps | grep c2name | awk '{ print $1; }')"
sudo pipework br6 -i eth1 $C2 192.168.66.2/24@192.168.66.1
```

---

Result:

```
./lab.sh
```

From the Container1 (I use lxterminal to open it in a new window):

[image: From container1]

Note that, as soon as you stop container1, corresponding pipework and iptable modification are lost and even when restart the stopped container, you will need to reissue the commands:

```
pipework br6 -i eth1 52b95d6052f7 192.168.66.1/24

docker exec 52b95d6052f7 iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

for container1 to act again like nat box.

Even commiting the running container1 to a new image and run a new container from it, doesn't help.